# Setting tab size in single line SWT text widget

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a view for an Eclipse RCP application and am trying to set the display size of tabs in a text input field. The text widget is declared as:

```
Text txtInput;
txtInput = new Text(inputHolder, SWT.SINGLE);
```

Trying to set the tabsize (to 4 spaces rather than default 8) using `txtInput.setTabs(4);` does nothing and looking through the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux/x86_64/3.6.0/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.java?av=f) for the `Text` widget there is a line to prevent the tabsize being changed for single line widgets.

```
void setTabStops (int tabs) {
    if ((style & SWT.SINGLE) != 0) return; 
    //rest of code to change tabStopsize
}
```

I have tried setting the `Text` widget to have `SWT.MULTI` style and the tabsize changes as expected but I do not want a multiline input.

What is the reason for the restriction on single line inputs and is there any way around it?

Thanks

Comment: How do you even type tab in the text input field? Shouldn't pressing Tab button on the input field just take you to the next input element?

Comment: Not if you use `addTraverseListener` and set it to not traverse (using `e.doit = false;` for TraverseEvent e)

Comment: There is a very old Eclipse bug [34805](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34805) about this which says 'tabs are invalid in single line Text'.

Comment: @Trengot I see. But it still looks like a usability issue to me. I'd say that if you have a single line input, user would expect the Tab to take him to the next control. Maybe that's why they decided to ignore the tab size settings for single line inputs.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the link. Seems odd that it'd work in v2.1rc2 (as mentioned) but not in 3.8

Comment: @dimoniy what the user would expect to happen would depend on the context of the input.

Comment: I've looked through the SWT source code and this is not an issue in the win32 version. The style test is present in the gtk/cocoa code

Answer (score 1):

As already established in the comments, it's not possible to do this with a `Text` and `SWT.SINGLE`.

**However**, you can simply use a `StyledText` instead :)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.Traverse, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            e.doit = false;
        }
    });
    text.setTabs(4);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Works just fine. Single line and tab key support.

Comment: Thanks, this would work except we have the text widget being passed to other functions that are all expecting Text widgets. It may be possible to change them without too much hassle but I'm not sure. I'll have to look into it.